# Pattern in java language

Tags: java, regex

I try to get from String like `(111,222,ttt,qwerty)`
list of values

- 111
- 222
- ttt
- qwerty

I try this pattern:

```
String area = "(111,222,ttt,qwerty)";
    String pattern = "\\([([^,]),*]+\\)";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(area);
            System.out.println(m.groupCount());
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(m.find()){
                System.out.println("group="+m.group(1));
                values.add(m.group());
            }
```

But I found that group count is zero. What I`ve missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have the same format of the string, you could simply try:

```
String[] split = area.split("\\(|\\)|,");
```

Comment: Note it will return some empty Strings in addition to those you need in the resulting String[]

Answer (score 0):

It should be `(...)+` not `[...]+` (character).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have words containing english letters and numbers without spaces,

You can use following regexp for achieving this.

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
```

It checks for groups of characters which only contains digits and uppercase/lowercase English letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is only one set of brackets ()

```
String text = "aaa,bbb(111,222,ttt,qwerty),,,cc,,dd";
String[] parts = text.substring(text.indexOf('(')+1, text.indexOf(')')).split(",");
// parts = [ 111, 222, ttt, qwerty ]
```